# Trying to click a button in Web Page, but can't find Class Name

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to click a button in the URL below, and download a CSV file.

https://www.ftportfolios.com/retail/etf/targetoutcometools.aspx?ticker=BGLD

The button has text that reads 'Click to Download'.

[image]

Here is an image of the back end.

[image]

I can't seem to get VBA to identify the button.  I have tried a few ideas.  Here is my latest attempt.

```
Sub ClickIt()

Dim oHtml       As HTMLDocument
Dim oElement    As Object

Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument


With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.ftportfolios.com/retail/etf/targetoutcometools.aspx?ticker=BGLD", False
    .send
    oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

For Each oElement In oHtml.getElementsByClassName("*" & "highcharts-button highcharts-contextbutton" & "*")
    Debug.Print oElement.Children(0).src
Next oElement

End Sub
```

It almost looks like JavaScript is being used to pull the data from another source.  Any thoughts on how to automate this download process?

Comment: The posted link it is not functional. The page address used in the code cannot be accessed, too. We cannot test what you try doing...

Comment: "In IE getElementsByClassName is available on the document, but not on SVG Elements"  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885991/using-jquery-find-to-target-svg-elements-fails-in-ie-only

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert relevant html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing in the console indicates you can click the relevant tspan

```
ie.document.querySelector(".highcharts-exporting-group tspan").click
```